# PySide2: How to prevent QFileDialog to close Sub-QMainWidget

Tags: python, pyside2

I have a superclass that inherits from QMainWindow, and its purpose is to call a function inside the Connection function instead of the normal CloseEvent (which would close my whole app) that displays the starter and kills the caller, and only if it sends Close, to actually close the app.

Anyway, I am now trying to call a QFileDialog in one of the derived classes inside a function, as soon as it closes (accepted, rejected alike), the CloseEvent is fired. The problem here is that my class is recognized as the caller and I don't see any way to distinguish the Close event from the dialog and the MainWindow. The event has no method or attribute "sender", and self of course always remains on the QMainWindow class (or its derived superclass)...

My Superclass:

```
#import 3rd-Party-Libs
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QMainWindow

class SuperMiniApp(QMainWindow):
    '''SuperApp for the common MiniApp-Functions'''
    def __init__(self, parent):
        '''initialize this class'''
        super(SuperMiniApp, self).__init__(parent)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        '''Overwrite QMainWindow's closeEvent, to prevent it from closing the whole App'''
        #if not from starter catch the Close-Event
        if (self == self.parent()._starter):
            event.accept()
        else:
            self.parent().close_MiniApp(self, event)
```

calling of the QFileDialog:

```
def call_dialog(self):
    title = 'Choose One'
    datatypes = '*.*'
    dir = os.getcwd()
    return(QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, title, dir, datatypes)[0])
```

Comment: Are you doing this to avoid application closure and intercept a closeEvent in order to show again a "starter" main window?

Comment: absolutely correctly realized

Comment: Then you probably want to disable the feature by using [`app.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(False)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#quitOnLastWindowClosed-prop) and emit a custom signal in the `closeEvent()`, in order to know when a "non-main window" has been closed and eventually show the "starter" window again. Then call `app.quit()` in the `closeEvent()` of that main window in order to correctly quit the application.

Comment: Many, many thanks. You have saved my life!